# why doesn't exec(chr(8)) delete a character from the shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, exec, chr

I know this won't work, and it'll produce an error, but I'll ask it anyways.
`exec(chr(8))` doesn't delete a character from the shell...
`chr(8)` is backspace in ascii. So naturally, I'd think it'll delete a character from the shell, like

```
>>> exec(chr(8))
```

would return

```
>>> exec(chr(8) # Missing a parenthesis.
```

Comment: Because a backspace character isn't valid Python code.

Comment: Why are you using `exec`?  What do you think `exec` does?  What would it mean to "execute" a backspace?

Comment: @Bren I want to type the equivalent of `chr(8)` straight into the terminal, but since we can't do that, we would have to use `exec(chr(8))`

Comment: @RobertoBassett: Why?  `exec` is for executing *Python code*.  It's not for hitting keys on the keyboard.

Comment: I don't think you know what [exec](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html) does.

Comment: just like `exec(chr(112) + chr(114) + chr(105) + chr(110) + chr(116) + chr(32) + chr(40) + chr(34) + chr(97) + chr(34) + chr(41))` would execute `print("a")`

Comment: And I am completely aware of that, I know that `exec(" print\(\"a\"\) ")` is a better replacement

Comment: But `print("a")` is valid Python code.

Comment: @Matt I thought that it would do the typing a backspace... I know that exec is just for executing python code, and that it's useful for storing code into variables and running it later.

Comment: data from your keyboard containing a backspace is sent through the IO and to your terminal, then executed when you press enter. It only works if you have something typed in already. in this case it was exec(chr(8)). Just like when you type all the letters of print and press enter, it does the same thing. I would argue a backspace is valid python code.

Comment: Nevermind I realized how dumb this question is.

Comment: And that I was arguing against valid answers.

Comment: To a question that I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, exec is for executing multiple lines of code in the form of strings. You should use eval. When you use eval(chr(8)), it gives the error 'unexpected EOF while parsing'. Executing this code will just result in a backspace where there is no character before, resulting in the error.